# Type '(foo: SomeType) => "a" | "b"' is not assignable to type 'SomeType'. Type '(foo: SomeType) => "a" | "b"' is not assignable to type '"b"'

Tags: typescript

I know there's a better way but I'm trying to implement a simple next theme function.

```
export type Theme = "light" | "dark";

export const nextTheme: Theme = (current: Theme) => {
  switch (current) {
    case "light": {
      return "dark";
    }
    case "dark": {
      return "light";
    }
  }
};
```

And the error I'm getting is

> Type '(current: Theme) => "light" | "dark"' is not assignable to type 'Theme'.

> Type '(current: Theme) => "light" | "dark"' is not assignable to type '"dark"'.ts(2322)

I might be having one of *those* moments, but why wouldn't this be valid? Would it be better to use enums to keep track of the different themes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your return type in the wrong place, it should be after the parentheses:

```
export type Theme = "light" | "dark";

export const nextTheme = (current: Theme): Theme => {
  switch (current) {
    case "light": {
      return "dark";
    }
    case "dark": {
      return "light";
    }
  }
};
```

Comment:  Makes sense, don't know why I didn't notice that. Thank you!